# codeigniter not returning data from database based on where condition

Tags: php, ajax, codeigniter

i am trying to get get some data through an ajax call in codeigniter based on the user input but i keep getting all result from the database instead of the matching ones.

here is my ajax:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".filter").keyup(function () {
        var keyword= $("#loc").val();
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: CFG.url + '/pages/filter_hotel_by_loc/',
            data: keyword,
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (data) {
                console.log(data);
            }
        });
});
});
```

Model:

```
    public function hotel_by_location($keyword){
        $this->db->like("location", $keyword);
        $query = $this->db->get('hotels');
        return $query->result_array();
```

Controller:

```
    public function filter_hotel_by_loc(){
    $keyword=$this->input->post('loc');
    $data=$this->page_model->hotel_by_location($keyword);        
    echo json_encode($data);
```

View:

```
<div class="input-style-1 b-50 color-3">
<?php echo form_open_multipart('hotels/filter_hotel_by_loc') ?>
<img src="<?php echo base_url();?>assets/img/loc_icon_small_grey.png"alt="">
<input type="text" name="loc" placeholder="What city do you prefer?"id="loca" class="filter">
</form>
</div>
```

Please what am i doing wrong?

Comment: your html input has id="loca", in your script you do "#loc"

Comment: try to print $this->input->post(), this will give post variables. You can identify in which key you are getting the value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your input field of keyword have id **loca** but you used **loc** in keyword selector and post data must be in json format,so your ajax code should be like that

```
$(document).ready(function () {
 $(".filter").keyup(function () {
    var keyword= $("#loca").val();
      $.ajax({
          type: "POST",
          url: CFG.url + '/pages/filter_hotel_by_loc/',
          data: {'keyword':keyword},
          dataType: "json",
          success: function (data) {
             console.log(data);
          }
       }); 
    });
});
```

and replace this line

```
$keyword=$this->input->post('loc');
```

with this

```
$keyword=$this->input->post('keyword');
```

and must check value of keyword which you get in post before pass it to model.